# How to do a license verification in PHP

Tags: php

Some time ago I started to write a license verification script. It looks like this:

```
if (! (ini_get (allow_url_fopen))) exit ('Configuration Error: allow_url_fopen must be enabled on your server');

define ("LICENSE_SERV", "https://admin.devilshield.pl/check.php?key=");

    $ LICENSE_SERV = LICENSE_SERV;
    $ LICENSE_KEY = LICENSE_KEY;
    $ licserv = "$ LICENSE_SERV $ LICENSE_KEY";
    $ lines = @file ($ licserv);

    foreach ($ lines as $ line_num => $ line) {
    $ license = htmlspecialchars ($ line);

    if ($ license == "INVALID") {echo '<div style = "font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; z-index: 100000; height: 7px; padding: 12px; color: white; position: fixed; top: -8px; left: 0; bottom: 20px; width: 100%; background: # 000000e6; text-align: center; "> Error loading AntiDDoS by DevilShield.pl v1.0! Please check the license! </ Div> ';}
```

This is "VALID" or "INVALID". If the return is "INVALID", this is an error message to the next part of the script

The problem is that it does not work. This error is always cast, even though such a license exists

**index.php:**

```
require_once ('start.php'); <br>
define ("LICENSE_KEY", "8080-8080-8080-8080");
```

I'm going to throw the files on a separate host to keep this snippet in index.php. Is there any other option than `define();`?

P.S. I come from Poland and I'm 15 years old. My English is unfortunately not perfect, so I use Google Translate

Comment: Dont you get _Parse Errors_? You have a space between `$` and variable name.

Comment: Yes.  Instead of using define, you should make this a _function_, and then you can pass the license as a variable into the function.  Even better would be to use a class.

Comment: and how would you enforce the user will keep using this code and does not simply remove the license verification..

Comment: @AbraCadaver Im not have Parse Errors

Comment: @cale_b How to do it?

Comment: or how to avoid users into bruteforce geussing valid keys like `8080-8080-8080-8080` and `8080-8080-8080-8081` end so on?

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you manage to fix what is in this topic, I will try to make the domain license assignment in the 2nd version of the script. For now I want to finish version 1

Comment: If this is your actual code, and you're not getting parse errors from `$ LICENSE_SERV`, you're not writing PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
if (!(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))) {
    exit('Something is wronguration Error: allow_url_fopen must be enabled on your server');
}

    define('LICENSE_SERV', 'https://admin.devilshield.pl/check.php?key=');
    define('LICENSE_KEY', 'error-8080-8080-8080-8080');

    $LICENSE_SERV = LICENSE_SERV;
    $LICENSE_KEY = LICENSE_KEY;
    $licserv = "{$LICENSE_SERV}{$LICENSE_KEY}";
    $license = file($licserv);

    if (is_array($license) && $license[0] === 'INVALID') {
        echo '
            <div style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; z-index: 100000; height: 7px; padding: 12px; color: white; position: fixed; top: -8px; left: 0; bottom: 20px; width: 100%; background: #000000e6; text-align: center;">
            Error loading AntiDDoS by DevilShield.pl v1.0! Please check the license!
            </div>
        ';
    }
```

Why not use **file_get_contents**?